# Add SharePoint list item, but not view

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I need to restrict a SharePoint list to some users where they all users can add items, but only members of a certain group should be able to view the items.

Is this possible?

I have an html form for creating the item.

Alternatively, can an Infopath form allow users to add item, but not view them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set target audience for your list view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working for my requirement.